# Kernel Compile crashing on Hyper-V due to memory issues

Tags: linux, windows, hyper-v, kernel

[image]

This is on a Hyper-V machine. I've set the min RAM to 512 and the max to 2048. The host machine has more then enough RAM.

Does Linux have an issue with Dynamic RAM on Hyper-V? I can't seem to figure out why we are having memory issues.

EDIT:
I also just disabled Dynamic RAM and set the min/start up to 2048MB. Still crashed with Memory shortage issues.

EDIT:

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1869       1240        629          0         27       1049
-/+ buffers/cache:        162       1706
Swap:          991          6        985
```

That is during the compile. I will post on the fail. Last time I did it, the system still had a good amount of RAM free on the crash.

PS: I've noticed that if I try and use `make -j` to use more processors(12), the compile will crash almost instantly.

Here is an example at 4GB Dedicated using the make -j option. The compile crashed right a little after `make -j`. 
[image]

EDIT3:
I was able to compile the kernel finally without using the -j option but why Hyper-V is giving me memory errors like this is weird. Still doing some debugging.

Comment: Exactly what is the Linux guest you are running?

Comment: CentOS 6.5 64bit.

Comment: But are you using the kernel that came with it? If you used a third party kernel it might not even have support for Hyper-V dynamic memory built in.

Comment: How about attaching `free -m` to your answer?

Comment: Yes. I am running the default kernel that was installed. Updated question.

Comment: Considered giving it some more ram than a meager 2gb?

Comment: I will try that next. But surely Linux can compile under 2GBs with nothing running on the system? Or maybe these newer kernels require way more then the older ones that I would compile all the time.

Comment: I've got a CentOS 7 x64 machine on Hyper-V with 2GB just for compiling stuffs. Works fine. `depmod` is crashing with over 2GB of memory in use, sounds like it's picking up circular dependencies or similar. Did you clean in between each build attempt? Where did you get the kernel sources?

Comment: I've done a clean and still had a crash after. I grabbed the latest stable off kernel.org and loaded the .config file with make oldconfig then did a make menuconfig to clean up the kernel some. This is the first time I have ever had an issue on Hyper-V compile.

Comment: I think it would improve this question to not have pictures of text but rather include the text inline. (Makes the text immediately readable, searchable, copiable, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make -j` (with no argument to `-j`) does not have an upper limit to the number of commands which are started. It parallelizes as much as possible, not just up to the number of cores (as the question sort of suggests).

`make -j 12` (or maybe less than 12 depending on how memory hungry each process is) is probably a more sane command in your situation.

From `man 1 make`:

```
   -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
        Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If
        there  is  more than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If
        the -j option is given without an argument, make  will  not  limit
        the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps answer half the question. Now if I just knew why it would crash on a compile with no -j option.